# QListWidget MultiSelection always does multiple selections

Tags: c++, qt, multi-select, qlistwidget

I'm using a `QListWidget` and enabled multiple selections:

```
mReferenceList->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

The problem is, that this mode doesn't behave as is expected as standard on Windows. Normally a listbox with mulötiple selections works in such a way that you click on item, click another and the previous one is unselected. Only when you use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LButton</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LButton</kbd> are multiple items selected.

Currently the listbox now selects one item after the other, when I click on several items. Is there some setting that enables this beahviour?

I'm using Qt 5.2 with MingW.

Comment: I think the `QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` is what you expect.

Comment: @vahancho, perfect, that was it. If you post it as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the `QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection` mode description:

> ...the selection status of that item is toggled and the **other items are left alone**.

I think the `QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` mode is what you expect, because for it "...the selection is cleared and the new item selected".